# Returning a multi-dimensional array from a function Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to find working days in whole year using Excel. I need that to create timesheet. The problem is I do not know how to pass multi-dimensional array to the function. In this case 2D array. I gets popup "type mismatch". Does someone has any ideas?

```
Function markWorkingDays(ByRef monthArray() As Integer)
    Dim mainArray(1 To 12, 1 To 31) As Integer

    For i = 1 To 12 'set all days as no-working (0 - False)
        For j = 1 To 31
            mainArray(i, j) = 0
        Next j
    Next i

    For i = 1 To 12 'set first and last day of the month
        firstDay = DateSerial(Year(Date), i, 1)

        If i = 2 And Year(Date) And 400 = 0 Then 'if leap-year
            lastDay = DateSerial(Year(Date), 0, monthArray(i))
        Else
            lastDay = DateSerial(Year(Date), i, monthArray(i))
        End If

        For j = 1 To 31 'set workings days as True (1)
            If Weekday(firstDay) = 7 Or Weekday(firstDay) = 1 Then 'skip Saturday and Sunday to Monday
                firstDay = firstDay + 1
            Else
                mainArray(i, j) = 1
                firstDay = firstDay + 1
            End If

            If firstDay = lastDay Then
                Exit For
            End If
        Next j
    Next i

    markWorkingDays = mainArray()

End Function


Function countWorkingDaysPerMonth(ByRef workingDaysArray() As Integer)   '(ByRef workingDaysArray() As Integer)
    Dim mainArray(1 To 12) As Integer
    Dim counter As Integer
        counter = 0

    For i = 1 To 12
        For j = 1 To 31
            If workingDaysArray(i, j) = 1 Then
                counter = counter + 1
            End If
        Next j
        mainArray(i) = counter
        counter = 0
    Next i

End Function


Sub main()
    Dim monthArray(0 To 12) As Integer
        monthArray(0) = 29
        monthArray(1) = 31
        monthArray(2) = 28
        monthArray(3) = 31
        monthArray(4) = 30
        monthArray(5) = 31
        monthArray(6) = 30
        monthArray(7) = 31
        monthArray(8) = 31
        monthArray(9) = 30
        monthArray(10) = 31
        monthArray(11) = 30
        monthArray(12) = 31

    Dim workingDaysArray() As Integer
        workingDaysArray = markWorkingDays(monthArray())

    Dim workingDaysPerMonthArray() As Integer
        workingDaysPerMonthArray = countWorkingDaysPerMonth(workingDaysArray())

    'display number of workings days in every month
    For i = 1 To 12
        std = workingDaysPerMonthArray(i) & "  "
    Next i

    MsgBox std

    MsgBox Total


End Sub
```

Comment: I might be wrong but I don't think arrays can be passed around. If they can then the variant type will be needed (rather than integer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 issues with your posted code:

1. `Function markWorkingDays(ByRef monthArray() As Integer)`**`As Integer()`**
2. Function `countWorkingDaysPerMonth()` did not return anything

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Function markWorkingDays(ByRef monthArray() As Integer) As Integer()
    Dim mainArray(1 To 12, 1 To 31) As Integer, i As Integer, j As Integer
    Dim firstDay As Variant, lastDay As Variant

    For i = 1 To 12 'set all days as no-working (0 - False)
        For j = 1 To 31
            mainArray(i, j) = 0
        Next j
    Next i

    For i = 1 To 12 'set first and last day of the month
        firstDay = DateSerial(Year(Date), i, 1)

        If i = 2 And Year(Date) And 400 = 0 Then 'if leap-year
            lastDay = DateSerial(Year(Date), 0, monthArray(i))
        Else
            lastDay = DateSerial(Year(Date), i, monthArray(i))
        End If

        For j = 1 To 31 'set workings days as True (1)
            If Weekday(firstDay) = 7 Or Weekday(firstDay) = 1 Then 'skip Sat, Sun, Mon
                firstDay = firstDay + 1
            Else
                mainArray(i, j) = 1
                firstDay = firstDay + 1
            End If

            If firstDay = lastDay Then
                Exit For
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
    markWorkingDays = mainArray
End Function
```

---

```
Public Function countWorkingDaysPerMonth(ByRef workingDaysArray() As Integer) As Integer()
    Dim mainArray(1 To 12) As Integer, i As Integer, j As Integer
    Dim counter As Integer
        counter = 0

    For i = 1 To 12
        For j = 1 To 31
            If workingDaysArray(i, j) = 1 Then
                counter = counter + 1
            End If
        Next j
        mainArray(i) = counter
        counter = 0
    Next i
    countWorkingDaysPerMonth = mainArray
End Function
```

---

```
Public Sub main()
    Dim i As Integer, std As String
    Dim monthArray(0 To 12) As Integer
        monthArray(0) = 29
        monthArray(1) = 31
        monthArray(2) = 28
        monthArray(3) = 31
        monthArray(4) = 30
        monthArray(5) = 31
        monthArray(6) = 30
        monthArray(7) = 31
        monthArray(8) = 31
        monthArray(9) = 30
        monthArray(10) = 31
        monthArray(11) = 30
        monthArray(12) = 31

    Dim workingDaysArray() As Integer
        workingDaysArray = markWorkingDays(monthArray())

    Dim workingDaysPerMonthArray() As Integer
        workingDaysPerMonthArray = countWorkingDaysPerMonth(workingDaysArray())

    'display number of workings days in every month
    For i = 1 To 12
        std = std & workingDaysPerMonthArray(i) & "  "
    Next i

    MsgBox std
    'MsgBox Total
End Sub
```

Comment: the same. If I add just "As Integer" (without "()") then it displays popup "Can't assign to array" and it points at line:
     workingDaysArray = markWorkingDays(monthArray())

Comment: thank you very much, its working now. I will read about Variant types.

Comment: I'm glad it helped. Variants are the largest data types that can accommodate any other type including objects; assigning an Array to a Variant works, but assigning a Variant to an Array may not (similar to trying to assign a Long to an Integer)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to use variant type:

```
Sub test2()

  Dim x() As Variant
  x = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:B3").Value
  Call markWorkingDays(x)

End Sub

Function markWorkingDays(ByRef monthArray() As Variant)

    Dim r As Integer
    Dim c As Integer

    For r = 1 To UBound(monthArray, 1)
        For c = 1 To UBound(monthArray, 2)
            MsgBox monthArray(r, c)
        Next
    Next

End Function
```

Comment: Sorry, I dont understand ur solution. Could u explain it, please?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not pretty sure if I made myself clear but the problem in this line:

```
workingDaysPerMonthArray = countWorkingDaysPerMonth(workingDaysArray())
```

workingDaysArray() is the function which returns 2-D array and I'd like to pass it as an argument to function countWorkingDaysPerMonth(). And there is a problem

Comment: `workingDaysArray()` **does not** return a 2-D array: it returns a **Variant**. You did not specify the return type for function `workingDaysArray()` and that implies its return type as Variant. You send the result of this function to a function that expects an array of integers and there is the problem